# Image rotation about the center in python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, image-rotation

The answer asked in this assignment is the following:
Rotate the image around its center (that is the point of coordinates (100,100)) of an
angle theta sampled uniformly in the range [10, 80].

I tried to implement my function [my function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M3M9.png), but if i try to rotate the image [my image to be rotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPHIG.png) I find a wrong result and I can't find where's the error. For example, if I try to rotate the image of 180 degrees (only to understand if it works) and I always get the wrong result. [wrong resul](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8N2M.png)
Another problem is that when I call the function the brightness of each small square inside the image is attenuate, why?
Thanks to all

Comment: You have included neither your code, nor your data. Code cannot be executed from an image, and a plot of your input will not achieve the same results as your actual input.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must want to understand the image rotation implementation method, so you can refer to the link below for the implementation method:
[image affine: rotate](https://github.com/gzr2017/ImageProcessing100Wen/blob/master/Question_21_30/answers_py/answer_30.py)

Code snippet:

```py
# affine
def affine(img, a, b, c, d, tx, ty):
    H, W, C = _img.shape

    # temporary image
    img = np.zeros((H+2, W+2, C), dtype=np.float32)
    img[1:H+1, 1:W+1] = _img

    # get shape of new image
    H_new = np.round(H).astype(np.int)
    W_new = np.round(W).astype(np.int)
    out = np.zeros((H_new, W_new, C), dtype=np.float32)

    # get position of new image
    x_new = np.tile(np.arange(W_new), (H_new, 1))
    y_new = np.arange(H_new).repeat(W_new).reshape(H_new, -1)

    # get position of original image by affine
    adbc = a * d - b * c
    x = np.round((d * x_new  - b * y_new) / adbc).astype(np.int) - tx + 1
    y = np.round((-c * x_new + a * y_new) / adbc).astype(np.int) - ty + 1

    # adjust center by affine
    dcx = (x.max() + x.min()) // 2 - W // 2
    dcy = (y.max() + y.min()) // 2 - H // 2

    x -= dcx
    y -= dcy

    x = np.clip(x, 0, W + 1)
    y = np.clip(y, 0, H + 1)

    # assign pixcel
    out[y_new, x_new] = img[y, x]
    out = out.astype(np.uint8)

    return out
```

I didn't answer your question directly, but maybe you can find the answer in the code above.